# Which Java Web Framework allows Cross-Domain Javascripting (http proxy)?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, vaadin

So just a quick intro, I am starting to explore Vaadin, and it's absolutely perfect. Previously, I was juggling PHP, Perl, Ruby, and Jquery for designing rich client web application. It didn't work out too well, as I've burnt out from trying to fix cross browser issues (aka get-it-to-work-on-IE-damn-it), handling server-side, client-side, and building a robust communication between the two tier had lot of code not related to application logic....by the time I was burnt out, only tiny bit of application logic was implemented.

Vaadin seems like the answer to my problem as it only requires Java and built on top of GWT.

However, I am curious how I can incorporate **Cross-Domain Javascripting** ? Back in LAMP environment, I had a CGI proxy script that loaded external URL, and injected JS into the proxy-loaded page. I used the CGI proxy script, as it rendered Javascript of the external URL well. Is there a class or package for Java or a specific Java web framework similiar to Vaadin that makes this possible ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid any kind of proxies, and thereby keep a full context on each 'side', then you should choose [easyXDM](http://easyXDM.net/wp). To see it in action try http://easyxdm.net/current/example/methods.html

This fully supports *all* browsers, and has a neat RPC interface that lets you call methods and pass data between the domains.
If you plan to support IE6/7 then you should also try the [upcoming version](http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/05/21/new-transport-for-ie67-as-fast-as-postmessage-and-with-no-dependencies/).
Even though the current version is fast (when used with a dependency), this one is even faster - actually nearly as fast as `postMessage` in never browsers!

Comment: Well nothing wrong with self promotion when your software addresses someone's question. Nice work! In fact I'm going to look into using this for a few projects of my own :-)

Comment: Thats what I figured too, waiting for 'others' to promote it hasn't hasn't paid off to much so far :)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily implement the functionality yourself.
a proxy for cross domain javascript is really straightfoward.
It's just creating a request equivalent to the ajax request you want and direct it to the other domain.

Comment: i dont quite understand what this means.

Answer (score 0):

[ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com/) has what they call a "[ScriptTagProxy](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Ext-JS/UseaScriptTagProxytofetchcrossdomainremotedata.htm)" which may or may not be of use to you...

Here's a few more links about this:

- http://xant.us/ext-ux/examples/css-proxy/
- http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?17691-Cross-domain-Ext.Ajax-Ext.data.Connection

Comment: when I go to extjs it keeps asking for username and password.